# Observable in NavParams

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, rxjs

my question is can I push a page with an rxjs Observable? Something like this:

```
this.navCtrl.push(MyPage, { obs: this.myObservable });
```

where `myObservable` is an `Observable<any[]>`. I want to do this because I need to 'listen' the observable in the other page. I don't want to pass only the subscribed data. I want all the Observable object. I don't think it's possible because I tried and nothing appened in the pushed page. Some help? Thanks

Comment: That is not possible. alternatively, you could define a Subject on a provider and subscribe to it on the page.

Comment: A simple example? Thanks

Comment: Maybe I can use `events` to publish an `Observable`?

Comment: I think the best approach in your case is to create an observable in provider and then subscribe to it on the component. I didn't get what is your use case here. Events are used to pass data and synchronize tasks across your app.